# Parsing HTML Tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

I'm a little new to jQuery, and i'm in need of being able to parse a document that contains a news feed in the following structure (sorry for the poor format, not great at getting code to show properly here). Can anyone lend a hand? I need to be able to grab the image, news title, and the snippet of news information.

```
<div class="article-list">
 <ul>
  <li>
  <div class="image-container">
  <img src="" /></div>
  <div class="content-container">

  <h3>News Title</h3>
  <p>News Information</p>
  <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="image-container">
<img src="" /></div>
<div class="content-container">

<h3>News Title</h3>
    <p>News Information</p>
    <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li>
   <div class="image-container">
<img src="" /></div>
   <div class="content-container">

<h3>News Title</h3>
    <p>News Information</p>
    <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

o

Comment: is it something wrong with answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:

```
var myHtml = "... some valid HTML  ... "
var parsed = $(myHtml);

var images = parsed.find('img'); // or some more specific selector....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var news_title = $('li h3').html();
  var article_img = $('li img').html();
  var news_snippet = $('li h3 + p').html();
});
```